# document.setAttribute does not seem to work

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple javascript function that creates a DOM object (in this case a tag ) and I call it in the  of my html page and it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
function create_link() {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute('href', 'the_link.html');
    link.setAttribute('name', 'click on link');
    document.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that traversal? You can access the `body` tag through `document.body`.

Comment: ok, I didn't I could access the body directly. I just tried it and document.body doesn't work either.

Comment: You can also access the document itself through `document.documentElement` and the `head` tag through `document.head`. Take a look at Mike Lewis' answer. It's what you're looking for.

Comment: It's not reliable to traverse using `childNodes` as text nodes (including whitespace), the doctype node, etc. can cause your method to break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The createElement and setAttribute calls are fine, are you sure  `document.childNodes[0].childNodes[1]` is defined?

To test, you can do: `document.body.appendChild(link);`, which should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely with `document.childNodes[0].childNodes[1]`.  It's suggested that you use `document.getElementById(id)` instead, especially since this is more resistant to changes in your HTML structure that may later be made.

In general, avoid using `childNodes` to navigate to specific parts of the DOM.